# SQL connecting date on table 1 to a month name on table2

Tags: sql-server

I have a table1 that has sales orders. I need to add the manager that the sales person reports to, which is not on table1 but table2. a sales person could change managers so if in january, his manager was John, and in december his manager was steve, I want the sale in january to show manager john and the december sale to show manager Steve. table1 has a date for the sale. but table2 only has a string for the period, like January 2015 or december 2015. How would I get the manager name that belongs to each sale depending on the date?

table1

```
orderID     orderdate     repname
10          2015-01-10     Carlos
25          2015-12-15     Carlos
```

and Table2

```
Repname    period          manager
Carlos     January 2015    John 
Carlos     December 2015   Steve    <-- he has a new manager in Dec
```

I want the end result to be

```
orderID     orderdate     repname     manager
10          2015-01-10     Carlos     John 
25          2015-12-15     Carlos     Steve
```

Comment: Give us some data , and what you try for achieving your target ??

Comment: I just added an example. thanks

Comment: is it possible for setting two mangers on a month , or we can say manger per a month or months ??

Comment: and what is dataType of period column ??

Comment: period (varchar(255),null)

Comment: and no, it is one manager per month. if someone switches managers, they will have to do it once they finish the current month.

Comment: I answered you. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are another approaches , but mine is as following...

**The key** of resolving this issue is

1) getting the name of month in date column. `ex: january`

2) getting the first word of period column. `ex: january`

then equals each other with using `Join` clause (Absolutely)

you can reach the first half of key via using system function:

> DATENAME ( datepart , date )

and about the second half of key use the next code:

```
Select SUBSTRING(period,1,(CHARINDEX(' ',columnName+ ' ')-1))
```

**Demo:-**

```
Create table Table1
(orderID int , orderdate date, repname varchar(30))
go
insert into Table1 values (10,' 2015-01-10','Carlos')
go
insert into Table1 values (20,' 2015-12-10','Carlos')
go

Create table Table2
( repname varchar(30), period varchar(50),  manager varchar(30))
go
insert into Table2 values ('Carlos','January 2015','John')
go
insert into Table2 values ('Carlos','December 2015','Steve')
go

select  orderID,orderdate,a.repname, b.manager
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.repname = b.repname
and DateName( month, orderdate) = SUBSTRING(period,1,(CHARINDEX(' ',period + ' ')-1))
```

**Result:-**

[image]

Comment: this one did it. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query for the given example. However question from @ahmedAbdelqader makes sense.

```
SELECT T1.OrderID
    , T1.OrderDate
    , T1.RepName
    , T2.Manager
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.RepName = T2.RepName 
    AND (T1.OrderDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, T2.Period) AND DATEADD(M,1,CONVERT(DATETIME, T2.Period)))
```

Comment: Hi Vamsi, could you explain what the last line does? the AND in the Inner Join. the period column is actually a string, but if it was a date it might work. I am just trying to understand what the AND does in the inner join.

Comment: Hi, The inner join is based on two conditions one being the repname and another to match the date period. So the last line will check as below,

T1.Orderdate (which is equal to 2015-01-10) is checked to find in the right period for example between 2015-01-01 12:00 AM and 2015-02-01 12:00 AM.

In the answer accepted, it wont consider different years, where as this considers even year.

This should work even if period is of varchar

Answer (score 0):

If Table2 *only* has a record when a management change occurs you can use ROW_NUMBER()

Considering this test data:

```
create table #table1
(
    orderID int,
    orderdate date,
    repname nvarchar(20)
)
insert #table1 select 10,'1/10/2015','Carlos'
insert #table1 select 11,'1/12/2015','Frank'
insert #table1 select 12,'3/15/2015','Frank'
insert #table1 select 13,'2/1/2015','Carlos'
insert #table1 select 25,'12/15/2015','Carlos'
insert #table1 select 26,'12/31/2015','Frank'
insert #table1 select 77,'1/3/2016','Carlos'

create table #table2
(
    repname nvarchar(20),
    period nvarchar(50),
    manager nvarchar(20)
)

insert #table2 select 'Carlos', 'January 2015', 'John'
insert #table2 select 'Frank', 'January 2015', 'John'
insert #table2 select 'Frank', 'February 2015', 'Jenny'
insert #table2 select 'Carlos', 'December 2015', 'Steve'
```

This query returns the expected results:

```
SELECT orderid, repname, orderdate, manager
FROM (
    SELECT  t1.orderid,
            t1.repname,
            t1.orderdate,
            t2.manager,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.repname, t1.orderdate
                        ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, t2.Period) DESC) as RowNum
FROM #table1 t1
    INNER JOIN #table2 t2
        ON t1.repname = t2.repname
        AND t1.orderdate >= CONVERT(datetime, t2.Period)

) salespersonmanagers
WHERE RowNum = 1
ORDER BY orderdate
```

Results

```
10  Carlos  2015-01-10  John
11  Frank   2015-01-12  John
13  Carlos  2015-02-01  John
12  Frank   2015-03-15  Jenny
25  Carlos  2015-12-15  Steve
26  Frank   2015-12-31  Jenny
77  Carlos  2016-01-03  Steve
```

The inner query returns all join records based on rep name, where the order date >= the period and manager. If they didn't have a manager change in the period, it returns their most recent manager change and assigns a row number where the most recent manager is the lowest row number.

The outer query returns only those in row 1 (the most recent manager change).

Comment: this is a nice approach. I just checked table2 and there is a new row every month, even it the manager is still the same. I will try this option as well. thank you.